# Express app.get not waiting for cheerio to load

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, axios, cheerio

I have the fallowing web scraper code written in node with express, Axios and Cherrio

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const body = await axios.get(URL);
  var item_number = 0;
  let $ = cheerio.load(body); //loading of complete HTML body
  await $('div.product-box').each(function (index) {
    item_number = item_number + 1;
    const price = $(this)
      .find('div.product-detail-info>div.product-price')
      .find('span.new-price')
      .text();
    console.log(price);
  });
  res.render('index', {
    number: item_number,
  });
});
```

The question is  why  `res.render` doesn't wait for the `cheerio` parsing to finish?
I am looking to extract info and then render them in a `ejs` file.

Thx in advance !!!

Comment: It does. Also those cheerio functions are not async, the only thing you should await is axios.get

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with what result you are seeing? Like how many prices are logged to the console, and what item number the request returns.